# tallying similar properties on a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 18:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 17:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"}]
```

I am using something like this to traverse through each time:

```
_.each(times,function(t){
    console.log(t.ts);
}, this);
```

I am using `moment` to make sure that the dates all have the same end of day time, so as to ignore this variable. I would like to create a new object with a count of like times, e.g.

```
uniqueTimes = 
{
 {"Thu, 20 Aug 2015": 4},
 {"Wed, 19 Aug 2015": 2}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I was thinking of traversing the `uniqueTimes` object within the `_.each` function, but I have hundreds of times, so on each iteration `uniqueTimes` will be larger and larger. This doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your usage of `_.each` it seems that you're using either LoDash or Underscore. In that case, both libraries have a handy `_.countBy` method ([LoDash docs](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy), [Underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy)) that would allow you to get your desired results as shown below.

Instead of the whole split/join approach I'm using, you could also use the regex approach that [adeneo shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773443/59111).

```js
var times = [{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 18:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 17:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
{"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"}];

var groupedCounts = _.countBy(times, function(item) {
  var split = item.ts.split(' ');
  var value = split.slice(0, split.length - 2).join(' ');
  return value;
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(groupedCounts, null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I am new to it, so I'm just learning the tools. Thanks for pointing out `_.countBy`. This gave a me a good idea of how to continue approaching the problem of plotting this data and so far I've gotten good results.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate and add to the unique times as you go

```js
var times = [
    {"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 18:00:00 GMT"},
    {"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 17:00:00 GMT"},
    {"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
    {"ts":"Thu, 20 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"},
    {"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 16:00:00 GMT"},
    {"ts":"Wed, 19 Aug 2015 15:00:00 GMT"}
];

var uniqueTimes = {};

times.forEach(function(time) {
    var t = (time.ts.match(/^(.*?)\s\d+\:/) || [])[1];
    
    t in uniqueTimes ? uniqueTimes[t]++ : uniqueTimes[t] = 1;
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(uniqueTimes, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you can use [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure for your task:

```
const result = data.reduce((m, i) => {
    const key = i.ts; // or format your date with moment
    return m.set(key, m.has(key) ? m.get(key) + 1 : 1);
}, new Map());

console.log(result);
```

Notice: check for Map compability in your environment.